# Cannot reach xaml element from cs file in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a XAML page. In this page i have x:Name="grid1", x:Name="stackY", x:Name="mylabel". I try to reach grid1 and stackY and mylabel from cs file. I write grid1.... or mylabel.... but cs file does not recognise grid1 and stackY and mylabel in cs file. It throws error as "The name 'mylable' does not exist in the current context". I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin.Forms.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"  
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XCMob"  
         x:Class="XCMob.testpage3"  
         Title ="Expendable ListView "  
         BackgroundColor="Bisque">
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <local:MainListView/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ListView x:Name="list1" Margin="0,80"  
          ItemTapped="ListViewItem_Tabbed"  
          ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"  
          HasUnevenRows="True"  
          BackgroundColor="Black">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout x:Name="stackY" Padding="20">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Title}"  
                           FontSize="25"  
                           TextColor="Azure"/>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="stackX" IsVisible="{Binding Isvisible}"  
                                 Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                 Margin="0,0,80,0">
                        <Button Text="Place Order"  
                                WidthRequest="110"  
                                FontSize="15"  
                                BackgroundColor="Chocolate"  
                                TextColor="White"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="grid1">
                            <Label x:Name="mylabel" Text="....." TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="Large"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

CS file is :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace XCMob
{
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class testpage3 : ContentPage
{
    public testpage3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void ListViewItem_Tabbed(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        var product = e.Item as Product;
        var vm = BindingContext as MainListView;
        vm?.ShoworHiddenProducts(product);
    }
    void showit()
    {
        mylabel.Text = "xxxxxxx";       
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you cannot access elements that are contained in a template by name.  You need to use databinding for templated elements

Comment: It should be mylabel. I will be mylabel.Text="xxxxx". But still does not auto complete.

Comment: Thanks Jason, i am new to Xamarin.Forms. How can i do that ? Can you add it as an answer.

Comment: I tried below but still getting error.  Label xlabel = (Label)GetTemplateChild("mylabel");             xlabel.Text = "CCCC";

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding

Comment: Since you've already bound a list to your ListView, rather change via UI, recommended to update the value of list "products" (or other more logics) in the ViewModel.